# How to convert string list with number list each other in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I want to convert a string list to number list. It is implemented in Prolog.

For example:

```
L = ['21', '45', '06']
```

should become

```
X = [21, 45, 6]
```

How to code this in Prolog?

Answer (score 2):

In one line: `maplist(atom_number,L,LO)` using `maplist/3` and `atom_number/2`.

Comment: Thanks ! Can you give me a example ?